# Format text in flow document table cell

Tags: wpf, string, formatting, cell

I have a program that creates a table, adds it to a flow document along with table cells that are populated with text.  Everything works great with one exception.  One column of cells in the table displays costs and they have been formated as follows:

```
cellValue = "$" + string.Format("{0:##,#.00}", int.Parse(cellValue)).PadLeft(22 - 
    cellValue.Length);
```

As it turns out, with this formatting numbers like `$   11,111` take up a different width then numbers like `$    10,000`.  I would guess because the font is not equal width for each character.

What I would like to do is be able to display the costs just like the are when in an Excel spreadsheet when formatted as Accounting (ie the dollar sign is left hand justified, the numbers are right hand justified and the numbers are lined up from cell to cell).

Example:

> $   10,000.00
>   $   11,111.11

If someone knows what formatting to apply to reach this goal please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too simple but at a guess I would use fixed font for the cell like "Courier New" so that all the characters are the same width and would align up. The downside of this is that "Courier New" is not the most elegant font to use.

I am sure Excel uses a much more sophisticated mechanism for aligning numeric values.

Maybe you should use something that better mimics a spreadsheet than a table in a flowdocument.